# How do we get the video og:description to appear with the posted video on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, video, youtube, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Ive setup all the correct OG tags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="..." />
<meta property="og:url" content="..." />
<meta property="og:title" content="..." />
<meta property="og:description" content="..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="..." />
<meta property="og:video" content="..." />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="..." />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="940" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="570" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

I paste a url of our website into status field on Facebook wall. It previews the video fine, it shows the image, the description etc, like this:

[image]

When I post it, it shows the image with the play button, but no description, like this:

[image]

The problem is that it doesnt show the description. What we want is something like this, I copied a url from YouTube:

[image]

Ive taken a look at the OG tags on that YouTube page and cant see what the difference might be. I noticed that og:type is set to "movie" on the YouTube page, but that seems to be outdated according to the OG documentation. Anyway we are using Drupal 7 and the Metatag module and it doesnt allow us to change the type to "movie", if we select "Movie" it outputs as "video.movie", im not sure if this is the issue or not.

Comment: Actually, never mind, I found that if I actually went through with clicking "Post", the title and description then showed up.

Comment: check this out as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482940/sharing-link-on-facebook-showing-video-but-link-not-clickable-and-no-descriptio