# Sharing link on facebook showing video, but link not clickable and no description

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, meta

I'm sharing a url which has meta tag for 'video' to show a youtube video when shared. Everything works fine and the video plays on fb, but not able to follow link and no description. If i click video title, video starts playing.

**This is what i see.** Clicking anywhere will play video.

[image]

**Expecting something like the following(as youtube do)** So clocking on play will play video and clicking link will take users to my page.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got It. I just tried comparing meta tags line by line with youtube. The point is, Don't use Meta property `og:video`.

Use only `og:video:url` && `og:video:secure_url`

Comment: can you please share a little bit of you code because i have tried give my urls in  og:video:url && og:video:secure_url but the video is still not showing in Facebook like YouTube videos shows on Facebook.

Comment: I just have meta tags like this.

`<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x522udb">`
`<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x522udb">`

Comment: Does not seem to work anymore, audio sharing is allowed only https://current.org/2017/05/how-to-sneak-audio-into-facebook-posts/